# How to fix 'source.lift is not a function' error in angular?

Tags: angular, webpack, rxjs

I'm using a custom version of the [angular project](https://stackblitz.com/angular/vmvalpqyrde?file=src%2Fapp%2Fheroes%2Fheroes.service.ts) `source.lift is not a function` when the **http get** call is made. The error is in `core.js` file.

How to fix this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 38):

We had the same issue as well. In the end it turned out to be an issue with mismatched brackets. We used the switchMap operator and the catcherror operator. But because we had the brackets wrong. The catcherror operator was taken as the second parameter of the switchMap (the result selector) funnily enough, this still compiled though. So please double check your brackets.

Comment: Good one - this was exactly my issue. Really tricky to spot!

Comment: In my case I had a double map `.map(map(mappingFunction))` instead of `.map(mappingFunction)` that triggered this bug

Comment: In my case, my error was:
`subscribe(tap((): void => { ... }))`

instead of (correct version):
`subscribe((): void => { ... })`

i.e. a `tap` inside the `subscribe` part :-$

Comment: OMG  - could have been looking for ages

Answer (score 12):

Got same problems. catchError should not be in tap brackets.

**Wrong: catchError called in tap**

```
  getHeroes() : Observable<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl)
      .pipe(tap(_ => console.log('Fetching heroes'),
      catchError(this.handleError('getting heroes', []))  ))
  }
```

[image]

**Correct is: (catchError not in tap)**

```
  getHeroes() : Observable<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl)
      .pipe(tap(_ => console.log('Fetching heroes')),
      catchError(this.handleError('getting heroes', [])  ))
  }
```

Comment: Nice catch! You've just saved me a lot of time :)

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error in my web app, i didn't get it fixed until i realized to test upgrading the rxjs version, since i had it at 6.0.0, changing it to the last at this moment, version 6.3.2 fixed my problem.
In conclusion is a bug from first version of rxjs, we should test it a little more, but so far so good.
Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check your webAPI.

If you don't have access to logs of web server you can set null instead of 'catchError' block and check with debugger your Angular application.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and solve by using catch along with pipe not inside as params of catchError

```
this.http.post(payload)
    .pipe(map((res) => {
            return res.data;
        }),
     )
     .catch(err => {
         throw of(err);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had this error a few times, more so whilst Unit testing but the problem is re-creatable in working code or testing code. But i realised this is only when I place the catchError() pipe after other transformational pipe like map(). I move the catchError() to the top of the pipes and it works fine again.

Incorrect:

```
obs.pipe(
  map((data: Data) => {
    // TODO: transform your data
  }),
  tap((registrationResponse) => {
    // TODO: transform your data
  }),
  catchError((error) => {
    // TODO: Throw an error
    throw new Error('Throw a different error');
    // OR        
    // TODO: Catch error and return a different observable value
    return of(false)
  })
);
```

Correct:

```
obs.pipe(
  catchError((error) => {
    // TODO: Throw an error
    throw new Error('Throw a different error');
    // OR        
    // TODO: Catch error and return a different observable value
    return of(false)
  }),
  map((data: Data) => {
    // TODO: transform your data
  }),
  tap((registrationResponse) => {
    // TODO: transform your data
  })
);
```

Whilst the above works - I assume this to be by design although I haven't yet come across any official documentation about it. I believe this behaviour is because the error you are catching in "catchError" is from the Observable and not your implementation/transformation. Therefore it would make sense to require to have the catchError() prior to any transformational pipes like map() si

Answer (score 0):

For me I was using `catchError` without `tap`

Wrong:

```
import {catchError} from 'rxjs/operators';

this.http.get(url, options).pipe(
    catchError(
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        // Do Stuff
      }
    )
  );
```

Correct:

```
import {catchError, tap} from 'rxjs/operators';

this.http.get(url, options).pipe(
    tap(
      () => {},
      catchError(
        (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          // Do Stuff
        }
      )
    )
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

For all the people who are facing this issue when using window in angular - I had by mistake imported window from rxjs and that was raising this error.