# TypeError: source.lift is not a function

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am facing issue while trying to get error response from API in case of error code 500

API Method -

```
 return this.http.request(method, endPoint, rOptions).pipe(
  map((response) => {
    return response;
  }),
  catchError((error: any) => {
    console.log('error', error);
    return throwError(error);
  }));
```

rOptions is for body , http params
Subscribe code in component

```
     handleAssetChange($event) {
    this.apiService
        .requestData(url, 'POST', { asset: [assetModel] } )
        .subscribe(
          (data) => {
            
          },
          (err) => {
            console.log('err:HttpErrorResponse', err);
          }
        );
    }
  }
```

it returns

```
err:HttpErrorResponse TypeError: source.lift is not a function
    at TapSubscriber.catchErrorOperatorFunction [as _tapError] (catchError.js:9)
    at TapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/tap.js.TapSubscriber._error (tap.js:55)
    at TapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:59)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.js:1754)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:28191)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:503)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1671)
```

whereas in network tab I can see error response `{"message":"Asset Error","details":"You did not assign any asset ID"}`

Ideally I should have got the response while doing console.log but I am getting source.lift error, Can you please suggest what is wrong in the code?

Comment: Is this any helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53092545/13258211

Comment: @MikeS. I have version 6.5.5 for rxjs also the brackets seems fine

Comment: What does your `rOptions` object look like? What is the subscribing code doing with the response?

Comment: @JeffMercado roptions is nothing but body options, I didn't add full code earlier, I have subscribe in the component

Comment: Everything looks fine to me. Can you verify that the `map()` function you're calling is the rxjs `map()` operator and not some other function?

Comment: Hard to diagnose but I'd set a breakpoint in the `catchError()` body and step out into the rxjs code and check that `source` variable. It seems to me like something up the pipe returned a non-observable and is causing problems.

Comment: @poojagupta The code looks okay to me, hard to diagnose. Did you try changing the order of map and catchError inside the pipe. May be try once by having the catchError as the first function.